# Prolog falls into an infinite loop

Tags: loops, prolog

Ι need to write each element once, for example, Belgium borders France, and it should automatically imply that France borders Belgium.
Unfortunately, the statement `borders(X, Y) :- borders(Y, X).` falls into an infinite loop.

```
% Knowledge
borders('Belgium', 'France').
borders('Belgium', 'Germany').
borders('Belgium', 'Luxembourg').
borders('Belgium', 'Netherlands').
borders('Denmark', 'Germany').
borders('France', 'Germany').
borders('France', 'Luxembourg').
borders('Germany', 'Luxembourg').
borders('Germany', 'Netherlands').

% Rule
borders(X, Y) :- borders(Y, X).
```

It shows me all of the following

```
? - borders('France', X).
X = 'Germany' ;
X = 'Luxembourg' ;
X = 'Belgium' ;
X = 'Germany' ;
X = 'Luxembourg' ;
X = 'Belgium' ;
X = 'Germany' ;
X = 'Luxembourg' ;
X = 'Belgium' ;
X = 'Germany' ;
X = 'Luxembourg' ;
X = 'Belgium' ;
X = 'Germany' .
```

while it should stop at borders

```
? - ('France', X).
X = 'Germany' ;
X = 'Luxembourg' ;
X = 'Belgium'
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the infinite loop, due to the recursive definition, use distinct predicate names for rules and facts (for example, `borders` and `border`):

```
borders(X, Y) :- border(X, Y).
borders(X, Y) :- border(Y, X).

border('Belgium', 'France').
border('Belgium', 'Germany').
border('Belgium', 'Luxembourg').
border('Belgium', 'Netherlands').
border('Denmark', 'Germany').
border('France', 'Germany').
border('France', 'Luxembourg').
border('Germany', 'Luxembourg').
border('Germany', 'Netherlands').
```

Example:

```
?- borders('France', X).
X = 'Germany' ;
X = 'Luxembourg' ;
X = 'Belgium'.
```

**EDIT**

The computation performed to answer a query can be represented as a tree. Prolog searches this tree using *depth-first search*, automatically *backtracking* when it encounters a failure node (or when the user presses the key ';' to get an alternate answer). During the search, clauses are used in the order they appear in the program. At the end of the search, Prolog displays `false` only if the last node visited in the tree is a *failure* node. So, to understand why Prolog behaves differently for different queries, you can compare the search trees that it explores in each of them:

- Both rules of the predicate `borders/2` produce solutions:

[image]

- Only the first rule of the predicate `borders/2` produces a solution:

[image]

- Only the second rule of the predicate `borders/2` produces solutions:

[image]

Comment: Thaks, its work but i can understand why in France is ok and in Belgium or Denmark throw an "false". 

?- borders('Denmark', Χ).
Χ = 'Germany' ;
false.

Comment: @KyriakosGian - It's only failing because you've asked it to go back and try to succeed one too many times. `France` will fail on the fourth try.

Comment: @KyriakosGian See **EDIT** in my answer. If that solves the problem, please mark the answer as accepted so that other people don't bother responding it again.!

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I have to ask some questions and everything works except for the question "Which countries do not border France" if you can help me with that.

Comment: @KyriakosGian You can define a predicate declaring the countries considered (e.g., `country('Belgium').` ... `country('Netherlands').`), and ask: `?- country(X), X \= 'France', \+ borders(X,'France')`.